# Are these Rails query syntaxes interchangable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
>scope :a, -> { joins(:b).where('bs.c': false) }

>scope :a, -> { joins(:b).where('bs.c = ?', false) }
```

Just wanted to ask whether those 2 lines do the same thing? The first one seemed to work fine in development but gave me a syntax error when I tried to push to Heroku. Is the first one deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these are more interchangeable, without syntax errors:

```
scope :a, -> { joins(:b).where(bs: { c: false }) }

scope :a, -> { joins(:b).where('bs.c' => false }) }

scope :a, -> { joins(:b).where('bs.c = ?', false) }

scope :a, -> { joins(:b).where('bs.c = :q', { q: false }) }
```

Personally, the first line is my preferred because you can list several columns within that nested hash without needing to keep repeating the table name/alias.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @spickermann. Even better when I can learn something while trying to teach someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Only Ruby 2.2 and above allow use the JSON like hash syntax with quoted keys, ie

```
{'foo' : bar}
```

Instead of

```
{foo: bar}
```

Of course in your case not quoting the key probably won't work either because of the `.` in the key.

This suggests you are running different Ruby versions locally and on heroku.

Other than that, they should be equivalent.